# Fetching the entire web page from a specific URL using Java

Tags: java, http

Can I fetch the entire web page, including CSS and images, using Java? That is basically what happens when using "save as" action in a browser. I can use any free 3rd party library.

edit:

HtmlUnit library seems to be doing exactly what I need. This is how I use it to grab the entire web page:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(new URL("..."));
page.save(new File("..."));
```

Comment: Please leave the original question intact, and post your answer at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I intended to post my reply at the bottom but my reputation is to low to answer my own question.

Answer (score 1):

Java has some built in functions that you can utilize to open a stream the external sources say a web server and request a page which would return you the source to the page. You would then need to parse the links to external images and css and requests and save them accordingly.

[here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0320__Network/SaveWebpagetoafile.htm) is a link to an example of opening a stream to an external source being a website

Answer (score 0):

maybe [lobo](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http://lobobrowser.org/&rct=j&q=lobo%20browser&ei=8HcETt6PJcyUOv7yhb0N&usg=AFQjCNGJU9TQLHdzDGWvju45-Arqwt5CYQ&sig2=6rHJin0fvod6pzk41eTR9w&cad=rja) browser help you. It is an open source free browser completely by java. It has some jar libraries that can be added to your project.